# Summation of complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

This is a series problem where the terms are complex numbers. I am looking for a better approach to solving this problem.

> If $\displaystyle z = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$, Evaluate $1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^{20}$

The way I solved this was to evaluate the terms upto the 8th term. like below,

$$
\begin{align}
z^2 &= i \\
z^3 &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} +\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i \\
z^4 &= -1 \\
z^5 &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} -\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i \\
z^6 &= -i \\
z^7 &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} +\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i \\
z^8 &= 1 \\
\end{align}
$$

Then evaluating the first 8 terms,
$$
S_7 = 1 + z + ... + z^7 = 0 
$$

Which implies that,
$$
S_20 = 0 + 0 + z^{17} + z^{18} + z^{19} + z^{20} = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3
$$

> Thus giving the solution, $$S_20 = 1 + (1 + \sqrt2)i$$

I have a couple of questions about this.

1. Just looking at the series itself($1 + z + z^2 + ...$) makes me think that the series is similar to a binomial series. The way the terms cancelled out made me think of a telescopic series. Can you guys shed some light on this?
2. While this solution works it took me a while to get there. Is there a more elegant/less tedious way of doing this?

Comment: @mathguy: the value of $z_{7}$ is wrong? there should be a  $"+"$ sgin

Comment: @mathguy, note that as soon as you got $z^2=i$, you could have gone right to $z^8=(z^2)^4=i^4=1$, so $z^8-1=0$, so $(z-1)(z^7+z^6+\dots+z+1)=0$, so $z^7+z^6+\dots+z+1=0$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, very elegant and concise! Thank you.

Comment: @Chandru, yup fixed that.

Comment: @Gerry's comment was just what I was looking for. Since it's not an answer, I'll accept @Joel's one which clarified that it's a binomial series.

Comment: @mathguy80, it's not a binomial series, it's a geometric series.

Comment: Doh! You are indeed correct. A geometric series with common ratio, z. I hadn't encountered a series where the terms were complex numbers, and got confused.

Comment: If I do not mistake the answer is $1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^{20} = (1+\sqrt{2})i$. Not $1 + (1 + \sqrt2)i$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. If $z \ne 1$, we have

$$1 + z + \ldots z^{n-1} = \frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$$

So it greatly reduces the number of computation

1. Note that in your case $z = e^{\frac{i \pi}{4}}$, which makes it faster to compute the powers of $z$.

Applying those two ideas gets you the result.

Comment: Thanks. So it's a binomial series. Does $z$ being complex have any bearing on the series?

Answer (score 4):

Use the formula for the sum of a geometric series and the fact that $$ \bigl(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)^{n} = \cos{n\theta} + i \sin{n \theta}$$

Comment: I considered that but converting to polar form would have been more tedious. :)